# To replace a string and append a string in perl in 1 file

Tags: perl

I want to replace a line in my file and after replacing it I want to append another line. As you can see here, I have to open and close files for 2 times. Can I do it by opening a file only once? Thanks

```
  use strict;
  use warnings;

   open(FILE,"tmp1.txt") || die "Can't open file: $!";
   undef $/;
   my $file = <FILE>;
   my @lines = <FILE>;
   my @newlines;
   for each(@lines) {
     $_ =~ s/hello/hi/g;
     push(@newlines,$_);
    }
   close(FILE);
   open(FILE, "> tmp1.txt ") || die "File not found";
   print FILE @newlines;
  close(FILE);

  open(FILE,"tmp1.txt") || die "Can't open file: $!";
  undef $/;
  my $file = <FILE>;
  my @lines = <FILE>;
  my $first_line = "hi";
  my $second_line = "sun";
  my $insert = "good morning";


  $file =~ s/\Q$first_line\E\n\Q$second_line\E/$first_line\n$insert\n$second_line/;


  open(OUTPUT,"> tmp3.txt") || die "Can't open file: $!";
  print OUTPUT $file;
  close(OUTPUT);
```

Comment: This shouldn't run with strict and warnings.

Comment: Yes, there are syntax error too, see `for each`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Three-arg open](http://modernperlbooks.com/mt/2010/04/three-arg-open-migrating-to-modern-perl.html) and [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) your file in `Read+Write` mode by `+<`.